# jQuery AutoSuggest - Drew Wilson

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use Dew Wilson [AutoSuggest plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) to get json from the server and display the results on my UI. My response looks like below:

```
[{"id":1,"surname":"Surname","forename":"Forename",
"address":{"id":5,"houseNameOrNumber":"357","addressDetail":"",
"postCode":"HD3 4GR"},"gender":"F","age":56,"yearOfBirth":1953}]
```

I intend to display following information in auto suggestion box:

```
Surname, Forename
357, HD3 4GR
F, 56, 1953
```

Can someone guide me how can i use the plugin to show the above information in autosuggest box.

This code gets the response back from server probably I need to add something to this to get it working.

```
$("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script", 
{minChars: 2, matchCase: true});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this mean then: "Please not that you MUST have an object property of "value" for each data item. (This is now configureable with the selectedValuesProp option)"

Comment: can you please show code of "http://mysite.com/path/to/script" actually the response should be similar to the array the autocomplete support.

Comment: I have got a Spring MVC controller which gives me a JSON back. I have already shared the response from server. ` @RequestMapping(value="/autoSuggest", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody List<Patient> autoSuggest(@RequestParam("q") String queryString) {
  return pemService.searchPatient(queryString);
 }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `selectedItemProp` and the `selectedValueProp` options referenced in the documentation.

EDIT:

You need to use the `formatList` option to combine different properties.  Here's a example:

```
$("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("http://mysite.com/path/to/script", 
    {minChars: 2, matchCase: true, 
     formatList: function(data, elem) {
        var new_elem = elem.html(data.surname + ", " + data.forename + "<br />" +  data.address.houseNameOrNumber + ", " + data.address.postCode + "<br />" + data.gender + ", " + data.age + ", " + data.yearOfBirth);
        return new_elem;
}});
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to use them in my jquery code. Would you be able to give a quick example.

Comment: is the function `formatList` supposed to be called once I get the response back from server. If that is so, this code doesn't work for me. I still get No Results found while I can see the response combing back from server correctly.